# All combinations of vectors

Tags: r, matlab

I am new to R and I want to find all possible combinations or products of vectors within a matrix. How does one construct a 3-dimensional array in R to do this? Also is there something similar to cell arrays in MATLAB?

I have provided MATLAB code which does this, however I need to do it in R. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Regressors  = [1 2;3 4]';
%
[ ~ , Nr ] = size( Regressors ) ;
%
Combinations = cell( Nr , Nr ) ;
%
for i = 1 : Nr - 1
    for j = i + 1 : Nr  
        Combinations( i , j ) = { Regressors( : , i ) .* Regressors( : , j ) } ;
    end
end
%
```

Will lead to this:

```
Combinations = 

    []    [2x1 double]
    []              []


Combinations{1,2} =

     3
     8
```

Comment: What is the desired result from e.g. `matrix( 1:9 , 3 )`. Can you show?

Comment: The desired result would be something equivalent to a cell array in MATLAB or a matrix of vectors (three dimensional array) which are products of all possible combinations of vectors within the original matrix. These arrays would be to test for significance of interaction terms in a multiple term regression.

Comment: Yes, I can read the question. What I am implying is that it is not clear. The clearest thing would be to show some input data and the desired output. Perhaps show the output from the 2x2 matrix comprising of elements `{1,2,3,4}`.....

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon Have included an example in the question to make it more accesible for non-matlab users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your question, the point where you are stuck is the creation of a multi dimensional array.

The easy way to do this can be found [here](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-create-an-array-in-r.navId-812016.html).

```
my.array <- array(1:24, dim=c(3,4,2))
```

From there you can just loop through it and fill each element with the correct result of the multiplication.